# Вызов метода из другого метода VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Если просто вызываю метод так: @mousemove="test2" то он отрабатывает нормально, но как его вызвать из другого метода "test1"?

```
methods: {
  test1(){
    ...
    if (...) {
      this.test2(); // Так выдает ошибку "p is undefined".
      this.test2; // Так вообще не отрабатывает.
    }
    ...
  },
  test2(p){
    console.log(p.pageY);
    console.log(p.pageX);
  }
}
```

Comment: у вас `test2` принимает аргумент, а параметр вы не передаете вот и ошбика

Comment: Да, я знаю почему возникает эта ошибка, вопрос то не в этом. Туда не нужно передавать параметр так как это ивент определения позиции курсора мыши, и я писал что вызывая метод так @mousemove="test2" он работает. Поставлю тогда вопрос по другому, как мне вызвать метод определения текущей позиции курсора мыши из другого метода?